# MIPS/Assembly how to repeat input on error

Tags: assembly, mips

i just started learning mips this semester and am having a hard time grasping some concepts. What im trying to do is, ask the user to input two number, first and last. The program should compute the sum between(inclusive) these numbers and if last > first (6>3 but 3<6, the user enters 6 first and then 3.) the program should display an error message and ask the user to enter the numbers again.
I've got it till the part i display the error message but can't seem to figure out how to get inputs again. Here is my code.
_

```
.data
error: .asciiz "Error: first must be <= last. Try again please."
new: .asciiz "\n"
tab: .asciiz "\t"
first: .asciiz "Enter two integers for first and last please: \n"
str1: .asciiz "first="
str2: .asciiz "last="
result: .asciiz "The sum = "

.text
.globl driver

driver:
    la  $a0,first
    li  $v0,4
    syscall

    la  $a0,str1
    li  $v0,4
    syscall

    li  $v0,5
    syscall

    move     $t0,$v0

    la  $a0,str2
    li  $v0,4
    syscall

    li   $v0,5
    syscall

    move    $t1,$v0

    ble     $t1,$t0, done 

    move     $a1,$t1
    move    $a0,$t0 

    addiu   $sp, $sp, -8
    sw  $a0, 0($sp)
    sw  $a1, 4($sp)
    jal     f2l

    lw  $a0, 0($sp)
    lw  $a1, 4($sp)
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 8

    move    $t5,$a0
    move    $t6,$a1
    move    $t7,$v0

    la  $a0,new
    li   $v0,4
    syscall

    la   $a0,str1
    li  $v0,4
    syscall

    move     $a0,$t5
    li   $v0,1
    syscall

    la   $a0,tab
    li  $v0,4
    syscall

    la   $a0,str2
    li  $v0,4
    syscall

    move     $a0,$t6
    li   $v0,1
    syscall

    la  $a0,new
    li   $v0,4
    syscall

    la   $a0,result
    li  $v0,4
    syscall

    move     $a0,$t7
    li  $v0,1
    syscall

    la  $a0,tab
    li  $v0,4
    syscall


    li  $v0,10
    syscall


done:   la   $a0,error
    li  $v0,4
    syscall 

    li  $v0,10
    syscall


f2l:    lw   $t2,0($sp)
    lw  $t3,4($sp)

loop:   beq  $t2,$t3,exit
    add  $v0,$v0,$t2
    addi     $t2,$t2,1
    j loop  

exit:   jr $ra
```

Comment: You just need to jump back to the start, e.g. `j driver`. What causes you problem?

Comment: yea i dumbed out tryna figure it out because im finding assembly hard, i figured my problem out less than a minute after posting this question. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out just replace the done part with the following code and it works.
leaving this here if someone needs the help.

```
done:
    la   $a0,error
    li  $v0,4
    syscall 

    j driver
```